# Panel won't slide out using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the gray panel to slide out. I would like the entire div (with gray background) to slide out when clicking "target 1", or "target 2", or "target 3" before the other colored panels slide in. Then when you click on "main menu link" the entire colored panel should slide out (not just blink out) before the gray panel slides in. Look here for demo http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/

```
<div class="main-menu"><a href="#target0" class="panel">Main Menu Link</a>
</div> 
<div id="right" id="main">
<div id="target0" class="panel active">This is the Target Menu<br />
    <a href="#target1" class="panel">Target 1</a><br/>
    <a href="#target2" class="panel">Target 2</a><br/>
    <a href="#target3" class="panel">Target 3</a><br/>
</div>
<div class="panel" id="target1" style="background:green">Target 1</div>
<div class="panel" id="target2" style="background:red">Target 2</div>
<div class="panel" id="target3" style="background:yellow">Target 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't slide when you click main menu?

Comment: The gray panel should slide out when clicking the target links. right now it is only being covered by the next colored sliding panel. Then the colored panel should slide out when clicking main menu and not just disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/L7v0w96s/7/

You are hiding your gray menu too early. Add a callback function to jquery animate, and it will be hidden after animation is finished

```
  $other.each(function(index, self) {
       var $this = $(this);
        $this.animate({
            left: $this.innerWidth()
        }, 500, function() {
            $this.removeClass('active')
        });
  });
```

And change your `"width()"` to `"innerWidth()"`. It will calculate width including paddings.

Comment: I was going to post a new question. But if you know how I can slide right (not left) when I click "main menu link" - I would really appreciate the answer. I like everything as is, only the main menu link slide direction. I don't want to change direction of slide for other links.